# Apigee Apple Push notifications fail with ClosedChannelException

Tags: notifications, push, apigee

Apigee Apple Push notifications fail with ClosedChannelException. No more details provided on the Apigee website.

Here is a sample payload:
{"aps":{"alert":"NZD/USD trend changed from DOWN to FLAT."}}

Answer (score 0):

The APNS system made some changes and we experienced this issue earlier in the year.  We deployed a new version of our application and no longer have this issue.  It was resolved very soon after it started.  Are you still having this issue?